# Override aria-label of ionic3 ion-icon

Tags: ionic3, accessibility, voiceover, ionicons

I'm testing out the accessibility of my my Ionic3 app using iOS' VoiceOver capability.  It looks like ion-icon uses the name of the icon in its aria-label attributes and is read out loud.  Is there a way to either override it with something else or suppress the aria-label for icons?

Example...

I have a button like this:

```
<button ion-button icon-right>
    Finish my postcard 
    <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Which gets read out loud using VoiceOver as "Finish my postcard checkmark circle".

Similarly for tabs:

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Postcards" tabIcon="images"></ion-tab>
```

Gets read out loud as "Images outline postcards"

In both of these cases, it would be preferable to just not announce the name of the icon at all.  However, it would be nice to know how to override it with custom text as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [ionicons compontent documentation](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/tree/master/src/components/icon), you can simply overwrite the aria-label:

`<ion-icon name="checkmark-circle" ariaLabel="Completed"></ion-icon>`

Since you're showing a check mark next to something that sounds like a task, I'm assuming the icon is actually carrying important information: The task is completed. So you shouldn't hide that information from screen reader users.

Comment: What to do with aria-labelledby , ionic adding for input but not its reference.

Comment: It seems that they did not intent to use `aria-labelledby`. Maybe the reasoning is that an icon that has a visible label next to it does not need one, so you would use `aria-hidden=true` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, I figured out how to suppress the icon's name when using the ion-icon code.  Just add aria-hidden="true"

```
<button ion-button icon-right>
    Finish my postcard 
    <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle" aria-hidden="true"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Still trying to figure out how to suppress it for tabs or to override the label.

Comment: `aria-hidden` is the cleanest solution for your button, as you found.  an alternative would be to have `<button aria-label='finish my postcard'>...`.  the `aria-label` would override everything contained in the button and would be the only thing read.   for your tab, i'm not sure.  what html is generated by `<ion-tab>`?